# Missing scrollbar on datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to use scrollbar on datagrid. Look at following code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomCopyNas.UserControls.FolderControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Width="700">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Folders, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Path">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox PreviewMouseDown="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseDown" Text="{Binding Path}" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I try to wrap datagrid into ScrollViewer, but this does not work. What i have to do, when i want to enable scrollViewer in my datagrid, how can i do that?

Comment: You don't need `ScrollViewer`. It's already part of default template for `DataGrid`. Where do you place your `FolderControl`? Is it by any chance in `StackPanel`? Basically is vertical `StackPanel` direct or indirect parent of `FolderControl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `ScrollBar`s to your `DataGrid` without adding a `ScrollViewer`. You can make `ScrollBar`s appear using the [`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Attached properties:

```
<DataGrid ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

Comment: i inserted the code like above and the scrollbar appears, but it is disable. Why??

Comment: Perhaps you don't have enough items in your `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 0):

Many functions of DataGrid can be automated for example scrolling. to do this you can use **HorizontalScrollBarVisibility** and **VerticalScrollBarVisibility**.

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomCopyNas.UserControls.FolderControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Width="700">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Folders, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Path">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox PreviewMouseDown="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseDown" Text="{Binding Path}" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```